# Replacing whole strings

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I imported a text and seperated al words by using `StringCases`. After this I would like to manipulate the text, for example to replace all singular verbs to plural. When I use `StringReplace`, then *Mathematica* search for a part of the string and replaced it.

For example

```
texttest = "walking walk routes walks"
texttest1 = StringCases[texttest, RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]];
newwords= {"walk" -> "walking", "walks" -> "walking"};
texttest2 = StringReplace[texttest1, newwords];
```

The result is:

> {"walkinging", "walking", "routes", "walkings"}

I would like to get: `{"walking", "walking", "routes", "walking"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
texttest = "walking walk routes walks"
StringSplit[texttest, " "] /. {"walk" -> "walking", "walks" -> "walking"}
```

> {"walking", "walking", "routes", "walking"}